# How much of Rise of the Runelords happens where people will object to my dinosaur companion?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, published-adventures, druid, animal-companions, rise-of-the-runelords

This is my first time playing this campaign and I have selected a dinosaur animal companion. We are attending the Swallowtail Festival, the GM has told me I am allowed to have the companion, however the guards will not allow it to travel within the city walls of Sandpoint.

My question is how much of the campaign (long campaign eventually reaches level 18) adventuring is within the city walls of Sandpoint and how much is outside of Sandpoint? Is it worth it to keep the dinosaur? Worth it to me would be at least 75% of the adventuring take place outside of the city walls of Sandpoint thus allowing me to actually use my dino buddy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you need to have a frank conversation with your GM about how much/in what situations he's going to deny you access to your animal companion.  While you won't stay in Sandpoint for the entire AP, you will go to a larger city for some of it, back to Sandpoint, and into and through other settlements over time. That's mostly during the initial part of the campaign where your companion will be Medium; later on esp, in chapters 5-6 you'll be more free-roaming.

Sandpoint is not a walled city, it's just a village, so if he's balking there I suspect you'll have a lot of trouble over time.  The majority of Chapter 2 is in a large city. I would certainly consider not sinking a lot of feats and other options into your companion specifically for the AP if this is the case.

I'm not saying your GM is wrong - I'd probably give flack for bringing a dangerous creature into Magnimar at least - but do press him on whether he's treating this differently than if you had a bear or whatnot, and if so why.